# Hosting rails sites; vps or shared, and how much ram?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-hosting, vps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I have 3 rails sites to launch, all of which are fairly small and consisting of a custom cms, one with an online store, and 2 sinatra sites which are mainly static, portfolio sites.

What would be the best way to host these sites (I've deployed on dreamhost shared before and some vps's)

Is it best to manage them together under one vps? e.g linode $20/m (for the cheapest option, 512mb and would that even be enough ram?)
or keep each rails site separate and host each one on a small vps? e.g $4/m (there's often lots of deals like this on webhostingtalk)

I'm currently hosting the sinatra sites for free on heroku but finding it a bit slow sometimes.

Comment: When you say heroku is slow sometimes, is this because they're idling due to inactivity? I'd say any site on heroku which is visited, and has content which is indexed by search engines won't spin down. Particularly for your static sinatra sites you could make use of varnish which would be very quick and not touch your application.

Answer (score 0):

Shared servers are not the best choice for Rails applications because you might need to install gem, configure libraries or compile extensions and these kind of tasks are generally forbidden in shared environments.

You can use a VPS. The amount of RAM depends on your several factors: your application processes, whether you want to host the database and caches on the same machine or not.
You can start with a low profile and upgrade the VPS while running.

Heroku is generally speaking a good solution. Before blaming it about the response time, you might want to ask yourself if the application was properly designed:

- Does it use caching or memoization?
- Does it use background processes?
- Does it optimize queries?
- Does it use HTTP caching?